# Restrict a Post Types Post Status

Tags: custom-post-types, post-status

I have a custom post type and a completely custom user interface to access it, and would like these posts to have a publish status. I know how to make them skip trash and be deleted immediately, but this still leaves me with draft posts and private posts.

Is there a way to prevent posts getting flagged as drafts or private? I can hide the controls in CSS but I want to do this in code to make sure it isn't possible, is there a handy filter I can use?

Comment: I suppose I would add a check to the `save_post`/`wp_insert_post` filter to disallow or making it impossible to save this CPT as draft/private.

Comment: I guess I actually might have missed something the first time around..what about the `post_submitbox_misc_actions` filter for example?

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if you could use something as simple as this: (similar to the suggestion of @ialocin)

```
/**
 * Use the "Force" on the post status ;-)
 */

add_action( 'wp_insert_post_data', function( $data, $postarr ){

    $change_post_status = array( 'draft', 'private' ); // Edit to your needs

    if( 'cpt' === $data['post_type'] 
         && in_array( $data['post_status'], $change_post_status, TRUE ) 
    )
        $data['post_status'] = 'publish';

    return $data;

}, PHP_MAX_INT, 2 );
```

where we just *force* the post status value when it's part of the `$change_post_status` array - before the post is saved.

(... or maybe I'm misunderstanding the setup ;-)

Comment: curious, there is the potential danger of duplicate posts if it tries to save revisions or drafts, I will have to test

Comment: If you spot something, we could then try to find a workaround with comparison to `$postarr`, for example.

Comment: Hey @TomJNowell, I had forgotten about this problem and got curious if you did some further testing?